# Incorrect syntax on setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, settimeout

I'm trying to make a faux loading screen, and I need delays between loading messages of about 20-50ms or so so that people can actually see what's going on before it cuts to the initialized screen. The button that activates this goes to the following function:

```
function gameinit() {
    for (k = 0; k <=1; k += 0.125) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var nexttxt = "Loading... " + toString(100 * k) + "%"
        }, 20);
        displayupdate(nexttxt);
    }
}
```

However this comes up as an incorrect syntax (on JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/YoshiBoy13/xLn7wbg6/2/) when I use JShint - specifically lines four and five. I've looked at the guides for this and everything *seems* to be in order. What am I doing wrong?

(Note: displayupdate(nexttxt) updates the <p> tags with the next line of text)

When executing the script, nothing happens - the sixteen lines of text on the HTML move up as normal, the top eight being replaced with the eight generated by the gameinit() function, but the gameinit() only generates blank. If the script is executed again, it just outputs eight lines of 112.5% (as if it was the 9th iteration of the for loop).

I'm almost certain it's something elementary that I've missed, could someone please tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: The first line seems to miss a trailing semicolon. What is wrong with the second line I cannot tell either. Of course, the code doesn't work at all, but that's not what JSHint detects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is another function can do this better ---- `setInterval`

```
   var txt = '';
   var time = 0; 
   var id = setInterval(function(){
      console.log("loading..."+time/8*100+"%");
      if(time++>7)
         clearInterval(id);
   },1000);
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! It finally worked. I tweaked it a little though, since it turned out I needed 16 loading labels, not 8, and replaced console.log(x) with the custom displayupdate(x)

Comment: Yep! setTimeout is the function that defers the callbacks after sync functions. here is another way : if you want to use `setTimeout` for this

Comment: var txt = '';
        var startnext = function(m){
         if(m<16)
                 setTimeout(function(){
          console.log(m);
          startnext(m+1);
         }, 200);
        }
        startnext(0);

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)** instead, you can clear interval using **[`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)**

```js
function gameinit() {
  displayupdate("Loading... 0%");
  var k = 0;
  var inter = setInterval(function() {
    if (k < 1) {
      k += .25;
      displayupdate("Loading... " + 100 * k + "%")
    } else {
      clearInterval(inter);
    }
  }, 2000);
}

function displayupdate(d) {
  console.log(d);
}

gameinit();
```

Comment: Make sure to highlight and explain changes.

Comment: Still has the same result - nothing. This time it doesn't generate the 112.5%'s though.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` doesn't work as you would expect it to work inside loops. You have to create a closure for each loop variable passed on to `setTimeout`, or create a new function to execute the `setTimeout` operation.

```
function gameinit() {
    for (var k = 0; k <= 1; k += 0.125) {
        doSetTimeOut(k);
    }
}

function doSetTimeOut(k) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var nexttxt = "Loading... " + toString(100 * k) + "%"
    }, 20);
    displayupdate(nexttxt);
}
```

Comment: Also doesn't work... again, it blanks out the lines it's supposed to replace with "Loading..."